# java stuck on array index out of bounds exception

Tags: java, arrays

I am extremely new to programming and i keep getting stuck at the same point. Every time I try to use an array, I get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:" and I have no idea how to fix it. Here is what I have started:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int i;
String format;
String[] value;
int[] number;

value = new String[10];
number = new int[10];
i = 0;

System.out.println("Please enter a phone number: ");
value[i] = input.nextLine();

for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++); {
    number[i] = Integer.parseInt(value[i]);
        System.out.print(number[i]);
```

Comment: Note the last `;` at `for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++);` After this loop `i` has a value of 10, which is an out of bounds index for `number` and/or `value`.

Answer (score 5):

Note the last `;` at

```
for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++); { // blah
```

That loop is equivalent to

```
for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    ;
} 

{
    // blah
}
```

It's basically just executing the empty statement 10 times. After this loop `i` has a value of 10, which is an out of bounds index for `number` and/or `value`.

Get rid of the `;`.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because

1. Your scope of `i` is not restricted in the way it should be. Had you declared `int i = 0` in the loop where it belongs, you would have found the mistake sooner. `for (int i = 0; i ...)`
2. You have a semicolon at the end of your `for-loop`. That basically just increases `i`, which, because it has not been declared as a loop variable, keeps the last value after the loop, which is 10. You then try to access `number[10]`, which doesn't exist. Remove the semicolon `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the ";" after the for loop brace.
    `for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    number[i] = Integer.parseInt(value[i]);
        System.out.print(number[i]);`